# How to access database data when using database extension in IntelliJ on Mac

Tags: java, mysql, database, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm trying to implement a MySQL database for my Application I am coding with JavaFX.
My database is all set up and running. I am able to connect to my database and run queries on the database extension (like the database tab in IntelliJ). But I really can't figure out how I could run some queries for let's say a method that should show the output of a query that selects some data from the database.

Do I need to create a connection in like a MysqlCon class even though I have one in the database tab?
When doing that, it can't find the com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in Class.forname(com.myswl.jdbc.Driver). I looked it up and read that putting the jar file in the /Library/Java/Extensions/ folder is not such a great Idea.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: JDBC jar needs to be in your project dependencies, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by “the database extension”? Your Question is vague and confusing.

Comment: As noted, you need to add the MySQL driver to your project as a dependency. How you do that depends on which build tool you're using or, if you're not using a build tool, then which IDE you're using. Additionally, doing `Class.forName("...")` is no longer needed and hasn't been needed for years. Simply do `DriverManager.getConnection("...")` with the appropriate JDBC URL and it will find the correct driver if it's on the class-path/module-path.

Comment: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Answer (score 2):

The database tab in IntelliJ IDEA is not related to your application. It's like a UI for accessing databases from the IDE.

You need to add libraries to your app. You can do it [manually](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html) (inside IntelliJ IDEA), or via the build tool (Maven/Gradle).